# How to get value from DetailsView Control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have DetailsView on my page. I set `DefaultMode="Edit"`. Now i want to get value that user will edit in this cell.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvApplicantDetails" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateRows="false" DataKeyNames="ApplicantID" DefaultMode="Edit" 
            onitemcommand="dvApplicantDetails_ItemCommand" >
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicantID" HeaderText="ApplicantID" ReadOnly="true"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />

            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Update" ShowCancelButton="false" />
        </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

I've tried many ways to get this value, such as:

```
protected void dvApplicantDetails_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        string firstName = dvApplicantDetails.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text;
        string lastName = dvApplicantDetails.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work... How to get this value using this mode. I know that i can use `<ItemTemplate>` instead of `<BoundField>`, but anyway it should be some way to get this value from this field. 
Help please!
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, trying to access the `Text` of `..Cells[1]` is not what you are looking for. You need the value of the `TextBox` control within that cell:

```
protected void dvApplicantDetails_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        string firstName = ((TextBox)dvApplicantDetails.Rows[1].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
        string lastName = ((TextBox)dvApplicantDetails.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I need! Work's like a charm!

Comment: Thanks so much.. You saved me! 
Not sure, why MS had to make this so difficult when they are giving Edit and Insert mode ! It should/could have been a lot simpler

Answer (score 1):

Bryuk,

Try OnItemUpdating event instead. You can get new values as shown below:

```
protected void dvApplicantDetails_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var dv = sender as DetailsView;

    var firstName = e.NewValues[1].ToString();
    var lastName = e.NewValues[2].ToString();
}
```

Add OnItemUpdating="dvApplicantDetails_ItemUpdating" attribute to DetailsView control in aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this earlier today...1up for the questions and answers that helped me. Heres a function I came up with.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sFirstName = GetDVRowValue(dvApplicantDetails, "ApplicantID")
}

public string GetDVRowValue(DetailsView dv, string sField)
{
    string sRetVal = string.Empty;
    foreach (DetailsViewRow dvr in dv.Rows)
    {
       if (dvr.Cells[0].Text == sField)
           sRetVal = dvr.Cells[1].Text;
    }
    return sRetVal;
}
```