# How to get a CheckBoxField from a DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, ascx

I have been trying to figure this out for hours. So sad! The structure of my `ascx` is like

```
<asp:DetailsView ...>
    <Fields>
        .
        .
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ThingEnabled" HeaderText="Thing Enabled"/>
        .
        .
        .
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

and the element I want is the `ThingEnabled` one.

**Setup:**

```
DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)sender;
CheckBoxField cbf = ????
```

Note that `CheckBoxField`s do not have `ID` properties, so I can't use `FindControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `DetailsView` uses cells on it instead of control IDs for each row it has, hence you can get `CheckBoxField` value using row, cell and control position like this:

```
// Page_Load is just an example event here, change to any event you need
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView dv = sender as DetailsView;

    // the checkbox uses checked state as its value to be passed
    // n = row/cell/control indexes where CheckBoxField has bound into, starting from 0
    // e.g. dv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox
    bool checkboxvalue = (dv.Rows[n].Cells[n].Controls[n] as CheckBox).Checked;
}
```

If you still want using `FindControl`, use `ItemTemplate` wrapper element and create a `CheckBox` control on it (note that you may need to use a `BoundField` with `DataField="ThingEnabled"` on top of `TemplateField` for data binding):

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ...>
    <Fields>
        ...
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thing Enabled">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ThingEnabled" runat="server" Checked="<%# Bind("ThingEnabled") %>">
                </asp:CheckBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Then you can access that checkbox control using `FindControl`:

```
DetailsView dv = sender as DetailsView;

// n = row/cell indexes, starting from 0
bool checkboxvalue = (dv.Rows[n].Cells[n].FindControl("ThingEnabled") as CheckBox).Checked;
```

References/similar issues:

[How to get value from DetailsView Control in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678889/how-to-get-value-from-detailsview-control-in-asp-net)

[Get the value of a BoundField from a DetailsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391719/get-the-value-of-a-boundfield-from-a-detailsview)

[Accessing DetailsView check box value](https://forums.asp.net/t/1615939.aspx?Accessing%20DetailsView%20check%20box%20value)

Comment: `Checked='<%# Bind("ThingEnabled") %>'` - You'll get an error stating the tag is malformed if you don't wrap attribute in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Its also possible to use linq to get any field within a DetailsView in this way.

```
// Page_Load is just an example event here, change to any event you need
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView dv = sender as DetailsView;

    //using linq to get the CheckBoxField control
    var field = dv.Fields.Cast<DataControlField>().Single(x => x.HeaderText == "TitleOfCheckboxField") as CheckBoxField;
}
```